# Incorporate a .tpl File type into TradingView pair chart

Tags: mql4, pine-script

How would I incorporate a .tpl file into a pair chart in TradingView?

Comment: Hello, what is a tpl file ? Why do you think it is possible to incorporate it in TradingView ?

Answer (score 0):

> ### How would I incorporate a `.tpl` file into a pair chart in TradingView?

The simplest way is to create a gateway, that will re-interprete all the **`.tpl`** contained descriptions from the MQL4/5 source-domain into the TradingView target-domain.

The MQL4/5 source-domain uses the `.tpl` files for describing what should appear in the Terminal's GUI - i.e. in the chart. The file has structured, ASCII-based, line-oriented description of all details in a trivial format of a **`<parameter_name>=<a_parameter_value><EoLN>`**

### There are just a few `.tpl` file principal components:

```
<chart>
      symbol=EURUSD
      period=1
      chart_parameter=value
      ...
     <window>
            height=100
           <indicator>
                     name=main
                  [ <object>...</object> [<object>...</object> [...]]]
          </indicator>
         [ <indicator>
                     name=...
                  [ <expert>
                          [ <inputs>
                                   name=value [ ... [ ... []]]
                           </inputs>
                             ]
                   </expert>
                     ]
                     indicator_parameter=value
                     ...
          </indicator>
            ]
    </window>
</chart>
```

All detailed parameters ( `color=255`, `create_time=131541....` etc ) are related to the respective objects that they represent, so all the TradingView target-domain re-interpretation is easy and fully in hands of the Source-`.tpl`-parser/TradingView-gateway-designer.